# Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, .net-5, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net5

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and implementing SignalR 5.0.0.0 in MVC project of .NET 5 framework. but unfortunately, I always get the connection error. can you please help me out? BTW it works for .net 5  with SignalR version 3.1.0.

SignalR version snippet:

[image: SignalR Version 5]

SignalR conneciton script is as follows:

```js
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/pushNotificationHub").build();

connection.on("Recive", function (notification) {

    $("#modal-title").text(notification.title);
    $("#modal-content").text(notification.content);

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});


connection.on("Connect", function (connectionId) {
    $("#CallerConnectionId").val(connectionId);
});

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Below is the browser error
[image: Browser error]

Comment: Please check the status code of the request `POST https://xxxx/pushNotificationHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1` in browser developer tool Network tab. Do you set a correct URL on SignalR JavaScript client to establish connection?

Comment: ohh thank you, it is 1. maybe TLS issue,  https://localhost:5001/en-us/pushNotificationHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1, how to fix this?

Comment: So what's the actual status code of your request?

Comment: I have the same and its 401 - auth with identity server doesnt work